# mouseover function of jquery not working on dynamically created div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a mouseover function to dynamically created elements using jquery

```
$('#schools').append(
    '<div class="mediumListIconTextItem" onclick="javascript:showSchoolReport(\'' + $.trim(this.id) + '\',\'' + $.trim(this.companyID) + '\',\'' + $.trim(this.companyCode) + '\',\'' + $.trim(this.companyName) + '\');" style="padding-left: 30px;margin: 5px;">' + '<div class="icon-newspaper mediumListIconTextItem-Image"></div>' + '<div class="mediumListIconTextItem-Detail">' + '<h6 id="header" style="max-width:100px; overflow:hidden;">' + this.name + ' - ' + this.companyName + '</h6></div></div>');
```

code for mouseover effect

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $(".mediumListIconTextItem").mouseover(function () {
        alert($(this.name));
    });
});
$(".mediumListIconTextItem").on("mouseover", function () {
    alert('mouseover works!!!!!!!!!');
});
});
```

none of the above function for mouseover works. whats wrong with my code. suggest a solution

Comment: This question gets asked everyday.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 2):

This is the case called `event delegation`. In here you can't bind the direct event to a dynamically created elem. try this as below:

```
$(document).on("mouseover", ".mediumListIconTextItem", function() {
   alert('mouseover works!!!!!!!!!');
});
```

Comment: can i get the id of element who initiated mouseover event

Comment: yes instead of `$(document)` you can change this with `$('#schools')`.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, you have to use `on` but in a different form. You're using direct event but you need to use delegated events

```
$('#schools').on("mouseover", ".mediumListIconTextItem", function() { .. }
```

For more details check section [Direct and delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) for **dynamically added elements** like,

```
$(document).on("mouseover", ".mediumListIconTextItem", function() {
       alert('mouseover works!!!!!!!!!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As elements are added dynamically you can not bind events directly to them .So you have to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$(document).on("mouseover", ".mediumListIconTextItem", function() { .code here. }
```

better use

```
$("#schools").on("mouseover", ".mediumListIconTextItem", function() { .code here. }
```

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

Comment: can i get the id of element who initiated mouseover event

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation :

```
$('#schools').on('mouseover', '.mediumListIconTextItem', function(){ ... })
```

For a clear and short explanation of how event delegation works, see this question :

[Direct vs. Delegated - jQuery .on()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on)